# Using Ctrl +V to match destination formatting

Tags: excel, vba

Using the following Macro in my workbook and have assigned 'Ctrl V' as the shortcut to run the Macro. If I double click into the destination cell and Ctrl+V it works fine.  If i just single click to select the cell, I get runtime error "PasteSpecial method of Range class failed".  Is there a way around this?

```
Sub PasteWithDestinationFormatting()


 Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: Alternatively,  if it can't be done, is there a way to make a message box pop up to tell the user to double click into the cell to paste and end the sub prior to getting the runtime error?

Comment: Please show the whole code you have, this is not enough to see the issue.

Comment: it works for me without the need for double click.

Comment: I can get this to work with single click, not with double click. Though there is no error.

Comment: Are you copying a cell or the contents of a cell?

Comment: It sounds like you are copying text and not a cell with ctrl-C.  This only works if the clipboard is holding a range object.  The reason it works when you double click is you put the cell in edit mode and as such the macro is not running the standard paste is being done putting the string in the formula bar that is in the clipboard.

Comment: Copying text from outside source using Crl+C.  You are correct, double clicking was just bypassing the macro. Could it be fixed to convert the copied text into a range object so the macro would work?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're assigning the macro to override the keyboard shortcut for paste, try <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Hit those keys in sequence (don't hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> as you type the rest.)

This will paste the values retaining the formatting of the destination cell.

Typing <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd> brings up the Paste Special dialog box.

[image: paste special]

<kbd>V</kbd> simply selects the `Values` option and <kbd>Enter</kbd> applies the selection. If you're copying formulas or a mix of values and formulas, <kbd>F</kbd> for `Formulas` will paste them while maintaining the destination formatting as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have an error create a messagebox telling the user they need to double click the cell here's the code for that:

```
On Error GoTo Message

' Do Stuff

Message:
Msgbox "Please double-click cell then hit CTRL+V to run macro"
```